# why my background-image transition is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to change the background image of an div without having any effect on the content inside the div. i wrote following code to change the background-mage. I didn't understand why firefox doesn't respond to my css transition. is there any fix by which i can make it to work in ie and firefox.

Html

```
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
</body>
```

Css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    height: 665px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('image0.jpg');
    -moz-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Jquery

```
 function preloadImages(array) {
if (!preloadImages.list) {
    preloadImages.list = [];
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = array[i];
    preloadImages.list.push(img);
 }
 }
    var imageURLs = [
        "image0.jpg",
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg",
        "image4.jpg"
    ];
 preloadImages(imageURLs);
    var counterForBackgroundImage = -1;
 function changeBackgroundImage() {
counterForBackgroundImage++;
if (counterForBackgroundImage > imageURLs.length-1)
    counterForBackgroundImage = 0;
$('header').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageURLs[counterForBackgroundImage] + ')');
 setTimeout(function() {
    changeBackgroundImage();
 }, 5000);
 }
 changeBackgroundImage();
```

Answer (score 5):

background-image animate property is not listed at [w3c animatable list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-).

Try using some trick such as [this](http://marcbrooks.com/2012/08/05/transition-tricks/).